# Encrypted text changed every time -Msrcrypto

Tags: javascript, html, encryption

Intending to encrypt the text through [msrCrypto](https://github.com/hakanson/msrcrypto)  (MsrRsaCryptoSample.html) .

I am able to encrypt the data and decrypt it by using the RSA public and private key pair. but still not clear with the fact , what makes the encrypted data change everytime i refresh the webpage.

What exactly is the purpose of following function :

```
function bytesToHexString(bytes) {
    console.log("---------------bytesToHexString------------------");
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        if (i % 4 === 0 && i !== 0) result += "-";
        var hexval = bytes[i].toString(16).toUpperCase();
        result += hexval.length === 2 ? hexval : "0" + hexval;
    }
    console.log("result : " + result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Deterministic encryption leaks if two messages are the same. This is particularly severe with asymmetric encryption, since an attacker can encrypt an unlimited number of chosen messages.

Comment: what function exactly makes that happen in this paticular example , i mean the asymmetric encryption everytime.

Comment: RSA is not secure unless you use random padding, for example, OAEP padding. This random padding (which you are likely, and should definitely, be using) makes the result of every encryption of the same plaintext, turn out to be different, unique ciphertext.

Answer (score 3):

Deterministic encryption leaks if two messages are the same. This is particularly severe with asymmetric encryption, since an attacker can encrypt an unlimited number of chosen messages. To avoid this weakness, standard RSA padding is randomized.

The code you posted is not related to that randomization, it merely converts binary data to a printable hex string.

Comment: can you help me out in figuring out what function exactly deals with randomization of the encrypted text in this particular example and what exactly is the purpose of converting the string to hex string.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is relatively clear. It's in the function name. It takes an array of bytes and transforms it into a hex string,

Comment: so what is the purpose , this hex string (result ) serves here !

Answer (score 0):

The padding scheme used in the encyption method is responsible for the random encrypted string generated every time.

```
 var cryptoOperation = subtle.encrypt(
        { name: "**RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5**" },
        publicKeyHandle,
        plainTextBytes);
```

where RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 is the padding scheme
      publicKeyHandle is the public key in form of bytes
      plainTextBytes is the messageto be encrypted in form of bytes.